# Is there a free .NET obfuscator that supports command-line operation?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

Is there a .NET obfuscator that fulfills all of the following requirements?

**Strict requirements:**

- The obfuscator must be free to use
- The obfuscator must support command-line operation
- The obfuscator must itself be written in a .NET language so that it can be run using Mono

Comment: First question in the "Related" section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337134/what-is-the-best-net-obfuscator-on-the-market

Comment: Thanks for the reference Eduardo, but the requirements here are much stricter than in previous questions. Please let me know if you find an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Obfuscar](http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/) is free to use, supports command-line operation and can be run using Mono.

Comment: Now here https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try also babel obfuscator

http://code.google.com/p/babelobfuscator/

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention the [Babel Obfuscator](http://code.google.com/p/babelobfuscator/). It is open source (lesser GPL) but does not support Mono. I don't have experience with it as yet but it does look promising.

Comment: Hi Henk! I'm sorry but the requirements are 100 % strict.

Comment: knorv, you may have to scale down to 'any' instead of 'the best'. It's going to be a very short list.

Comment: Hi Henk! Thanks for the suggestion. The question and the title has now been changed.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx#downloads